# Inserting into database a datetime with the current UTC time

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, java-8

I'm attempting to insert a datetime into a mysql database for the current UTC time via the GETUTCDATE() function in sql. It's failing with "FUNCTION GETUTCDATE DOES NOT EXIST".

Is a way for me to get the current UTC time in sql datetime format from Java, and simply insert it as a string?

Another big issue I'm having is I need to convert the above utc datetime object into local time zones and I don't really know how to do that through standard java api's.

Comment: have you tried providing a value from Java?

Comment: I don't know what a datetime from sql corresponds to in Java, so I'm not sure what to pass.

Comment: Assuming that in MySQL you are using `datetime` or another appropriate date-time datatype (as you should), don’t insert a string. If a value from Java, give it as a proper date-time type from java.time, for example `OffsetDateTime` as in [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53331287/5772882).

Comment: If your type in MySQL is `datetime`, I believe `LocalDateTime` in Java will be the best fit, but beware that neither defines a unique point in time since they don’t include time zone.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement      // Using a `PreparedStatement` avoids SQL-injection security risk.
.setObject(              // As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange java.time objects with a database via `getObject`/`setObject` methods.
    … ,                  // Indicate which `?` placeholder in your SQL statement.
    OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
) ;
```

## java.time

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible old date-time classes.

Get the current moment in UTC using [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

MySQL 8.0 uses a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), for six decimal places in a fractional second. The *java.time* classes carry a finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). So you may want to [truncate any existing nanos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) from your `OffsetDateTime`. Specify your desired resolution with [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = 
    OffsetDateTime
    .now( 
        ZoneOffset.UTC 
    ) 
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROS ) 
;
```

Send to your database via a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type. For MySQL 8.0, that would be the type [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

And retrieval via a `ResultSet`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To see this moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
OffsetDateTime utc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String sql_date = utc.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")); //here, you can change the format of SQL date as you need
```

You would need to import the classes as follows:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question asked for that: "*and simply insert it as a string*"

Comment: Sorry missed that part didn't I?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense does it.  `GETUTCDATE()` returns a date time object, so why is he wanting a String?  Maybe can you show him the proper way to go

Comment: **No, no, no, incorrect.** You are mixing the modern *java.time* classes (`OffsetDateTime`, `ZoneOffset`) with the terrible old legacy classes ( `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`).

Comment: @BasilBourque What's the problem of doing that? It's working well. Any clues?

Comment: Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those terrible old date-time classes when they adopted JSR 310 and agreed to put the *java.time* implementation into Java. So you should give up on them as well.